# Spring JPA could not handle multiple transactions in one thread properly

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I have the following code fragment. After I invoke `BatchSettleService.batchSettleWork(Array.asList([1,2,3]))`. I found that the account balance only reduce 1 in DB. The debug result is every time `accountRepository.findByIdForUpdate(2)` returns the original Account without any change operated in the past loops. I have tried `Isolation.SERIALIZABLE` level but the result is the same. The data base I am using is MySQL 5.7.20 InnoDb Engine. The JPA implemention is Hibernate. I am expecting the account balance to be reduced 3. Is there something wrong with my understanding of transaction? Thank you in advance!

```
@Service
public class BatchSettleService {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private WorkSettleService workSettleService;

    public List<WorkSettleResponse> batchSettleWork(List<Long> workIds) {
        List<WorkSettleResponse> results= new ArrayList<>();
        for(Long workId:workIds) {
            try {
                results.add(workSettleService.settleWork(new WorkSettleRequest(workId)));
            } catch (WrappedException e) {
                results.add(new WorkSettleResponse(workId,e.getErrCode(),e.getMessage()));
                logger.error("Settle work failed for {}",workId,e);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

}


   public class WorkSettleService{

        @Autowired
        private AccountRepository accountRepository;

        @Transactional(rollbackFor= {WorkSettleException.class,RuntimeException.class},propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
        public WorkSettleResponse settleWork(WorkSettleRequest req){
             Account account = accountRepository.findByIdForUpdate(2);
             Integer balance = account .getBalance();
             accountRepository.updateBalanceById(account.getId(),balance-1)
        }
    }


    public interface AccountRepository extends Repository<Account, Integer> {

        public Account findById(Integer id);

        @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
        @Query("select ac from Account a where a.id = ?1")
        public Account findByIdForUpdate(Integer id);

        @Modifying
        @Query("update Account a set a.balance = ?2 where a.id = ?1")
        public int updateBalanceById(Integer id,Integer balance);

}
```

Comment: @Gab Yes I want to prevent concurrent read. But I am not clear the difference between PESSIMISTIC_READ and PESSIMISTIC_WRITE so I chosed the strict one. Thank you for your comment

Comment: PESSIMISTIC_READ prevent concurrent write (shared lock) and PESSIMISTIC_WRITE prevent also concurrent read (exclusive lock). The way you code it indeed need an exclusive lock

Comment: Isn't there a typo in  @Query("select **ac** from Account a where a.id = ?1")

Comment: Imho your expectation is correct

Comment: @Gab Yes , the difference seems clear to me now . I made the right choice luckly ,haha. And could you please do me a favour to study this case?

Comment: @Gab Yes it is a typo. sorry...

Comment: Well I tried :) don't see what's wrong in your test case. It seems you're retrieving a cached Account instance from EM 1st level cache and it shouldn't be the case (you should get a new fresh EM instance for each transaction) I don't know much about spring-data but something seems flawed here

Answer (score 0):

This case has been solved.
Using `account.setBalance(balance-1)` instead of `accountRepository.updateBalanceById(account.getId(),balance-1)`.
I don't know why `@Modifying` annoation doesn't update the EM cache while `@Query` fetch data from EM cache, a bit strage for Spring JPA implemention.